# How can I save the query results to global variable?

Tags: javascript, react-native, sqlite, expo

I want to save query result to global variable.

I'll use global variable **data** on ReactNative using Chart.js.

How can I do? Is there any other way?

```
var query = "select * from hepi;";

var data;

db.all(query, [], (err, rows) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    data = rows;
    
});

console.log(data); // undefined. I can't use variable for Chart.js
```

Comment: Do not try to store it to a global variable, write the code that uses it inside the callback. Global variables are usually bad, especially when doing asynchronism.

Comment: It *is* assigning it to `data` but only after the `console.log()` call.

Answer (score 0):

That `db.all` is asynchronous. It means that the code inside the callback is not immediately called (for example, connecting to the db and retrieving the query can take time).

So, here's what's happening:

You define a `var data`, then you query the db but the results are not retrieved synchronously. So, the `console.log` is executed, obviously printing undefined. You have to move that console.log (and every other code you want to run with `data`) inside the callback, or you can use promises.